Should we help bypass captchas?
You may label me a wet blanket for this, and that's fine.
There is an entire microindustry based around bypassing captcha tests on web sites.  The whole concept is unethical and of questionable legality, so I'm wondering whether questions  about bypassing captchas should be allowed on StackOverflow.
Some captchas are trying to prevent the theft of copyrighted information, while others are more generic, so maybe there is a judgement call to be made.

I would say "NO", (= Don't help). Yep, "entire microindustry based around bypassing captcha tests", and as a SME in one of the Web-Automation Tools, I have the "knowledge" to do so, but I've always refused to help other Users as those Users asking for help are usually just "Script Kiddies" sickening the Internet... It has always been a  "Cat and Mouse" Game between Web-Site Owners and Web-Automators/Scrappers (the Automators have always won btw, nearly cute to now see SO/SE trying to prevent other Actors from scrapping Content for LLM's), but better to not democratize that knowledge...

And that'a part of my concern here.  Many "script kiddies" might not even REALIZE that what they're doing is ethically questionable.  Maybe they don't care, but someone should point it out.

"ethically" + "but someone should point it out.", ah-ah...! Eh beh..., well, this is exactly what I've being trying to convey since 2013, and [2015-2024] as the sole Mod (independent, not even affiliated) for the Company Forum for the Web-Automation Tool [imacros] I said I was a SME, like also mentioned in my Profile on SO: "For iMacros Qt's, I (ethically) don't help for Social Media (Like/Follow/Comment/Chatbot/etc...) + Games/Votes/Competition/Spam/Hacking/DDoS/ Captcha /Bitcoin/Financial Win/Scalping.". // Notice btw that "Captcha" is just one bit in a much longer list...?

Stack Overflow is not about helping people, it's about building a knowledge repository so people can help themselves. There are no rules surrounding putting code in an answer which someone else might use to break the law - that's pretty much all code. The best example of that is questions surrounding viruses and malware. Information provided to help write a scanner can also be used to write better malware. There is no rule against that information existing on Stack Overflow.

That seems questionable.  Do you really think we bear no responsibility to uphold some standard of ethics in the site's content?

Only the documented ones by the people who own the site, not the one you make up yourself because of your own personal ethics. There is absolutely no obligation to post an answer you yourself are morally against, that should be enough. Side note: I would on the other hand be pretty surprised if such questions are not heavily downvoted.
